# WordPress Dividing posts over columns dynamically

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've been building a WordPress template based on inuitcss to get a responsive page.

In this template, I'm attempting to get the WP posts from a certain category, and divide them over a predefined amount of columns. To achieve this I'm counting the amount of posts from category and compute the necessary data for the posts to split up evenly.

I've been using [this](http://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/) (last on the page) example and updated several deprecated functions.

The issue I am facing at the moment is that all columns are loading the same posts, and they are only loading the last two instead of all available posts in the category.

The code below is what I am using at the moment, the result can be found at http://www.alikivanderkruijs.com/wp (click on 'Projects').

I've been sitting on this for a while and can't seem to get it right. I hope someone can help me out!

```
<?php
$proj_posts = get_posts('cat=15');
$count_proj_posts = count($proj_posts);
$split_proj_posts = round($count_proj_posts/2);
?>
<div class="gw">
        <div id="menuwrap">
            <h3 class="work">PROJECTS</h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="g  one-sixth  lap-one-sixth  nomob">
                    &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="g  two-sixths  lap-two-sixths  palm-one-whole">
                        <div class="content">
                        <?php query_posts('cat=15&showposts=' . $split_proj_posts . ''); ?>
                        <?php $posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=' . $split_proj_posts . '&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php static $proj_count1 = 0; if ($proj_count1 == $split_proj_posts) { break; } else { ?>
                            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php $proj_count1++; } ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g  two-sixths  lap-two-sixths  palm-one-whole">
                        <div class="content">
                            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
                            <?php query_posts('cat=15&showposts=' . $split_proj_posts . ''); ?>
                            <?php $posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=' . $split_proj_posts . '&offset=' . $split_proj_posts . ''); foreach ($posts as $post) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php static $proj_count2 = 0; if ($proj_count2 == $split_proj_posts) { break; } else { ?>
                            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php $proj_count2++; } ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g  one-sixth  lap-one-sixth  nomob">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it, simply get all the posts and count up until half, then echo out the closing and opening tags to create a new row:

```
          <div class="gw">
                <div id="menuwrap">
                    <h3 class="work">PROJECTS</h3>

                    <div>
                        <div class="g  one-sixth  lap-one-sixth  nomob">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="g  two-sixths  lap-two-sixths  palm-one-whole">
                            <div class="content">
                                <?php
                                $args = array(
                                    'numberposts' => -1,
                                    'posts_per_page' => '',
                                    'offset' => 0,
                                    'category' => '15',
                                    'orderby' => 'post_date',
                                    'order' => 'DESC',
                                    'include' => '',
                                    'exclude' => '',
                                    'meta_key' => '',
                                    'meta_value' => '',
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'post_mime_type' => '',
                                    'post_parent' => '',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'suppress_filters' => true);
                                $posts_array = get_posts($args);
                                $split_at = round(count($posts_array)/2)-1;
                                $count = 0;
                                foreach ($posts_array as $post_object):setup_postdata($post);
                                    ?>
                                    <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"
                                               title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </h4>
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                    //IF we are halfway through, close 1st row and 
                                      start a new one
                                    if ($count == $split_at) {
                                        ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="g  two-sixths  lap-two-sixths  palm-one-whole">
                            <div class="content">
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                    $count++; ?>

                                    <?
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="g  one-sixth  lap-one-sixth  nomob">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have left the full args array, incase it is usefull to others, but you only need to use the cat argument in your case.

EDIT ok, setup_postdata is flawed, just checked the docs and it doesnt work as expected. The suggested workaround is to set the global post object like so:

```
  setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object )
```

Change that section should fix that issue. The count problem is still weird though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user574632. This does indeed look a lot more tidy, but for some reason it's not working for me yet. I am trying to find out what's going on (I'm getting a completely blank page, even with php error reporting on). I'll report back here when I've found what's going wrong.

Comment: @KlaasM Sure. Did you make sure that the comment //IF we are.... is on one line? i ask because stackoverflow has chopped it into two, which would cause a php error unless you comment out the second line as well, by adding two forward slashes: //start a new one.

Comment: Yeah I got rid of that one – I think it might have had something to do with an additional div that crept up from somewhere. The issue now however is that, for some reason, it only displays the last post entry, ignoring the category request [Image](http://i.minus.com/ibqtg3fYkmqITY.png). Also, the count appears to be off which seems rather strange to me.. [Image](http://i.minus.com/ibjMrOQfJ8bu1f.png). To test I wrote 
    $countit = count($posts_array);
    echo 'Amount of posts: ' . $countit;

and as seen at alikivanderkruijs.com/wp, it counts only 5 entries while there are 7.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, while editing the previous comment the reference to @user574632 fell off.

Comment: Nice one @user574632, that did indeed fix the posts! The counting issue is indeed still very strange.

Comment: I found the solution @user574632. I'm not exactly sure why, but WordPress wasn't returning all posts from get_post(). The solution is to add 'numberposts' => -1, to the array of arguments. If you could add this to your answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: @KlaasM nice catch, edited my answer, and glad you got it working

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @user574632, accepted your answer, thanks again.